# SVN logs not giving the right dates

Tags: linux, svn

The command I'm running (I'm using python) is:

`output = subprocess.Popen(['svn', 'log',<repo url>,'-r', '{2012-12-10}:{2012-12-12}'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]`

which translates to

`svn log <repo url> -r {2012-12-10}:{2012-12-12}`

However, it's giving me occasional responses from November or October (and possibly other times; I wanted to specify two days for a reason)

What's going on here?

Thanks

Comment: I have no problems with it... but is there anywhere in the code or interpretation which could confuse American & Proper formatting of dates (by which I mean month & date value switched)?

Comment: Not in the python script on which I'm working. I'm going to try reversing them and seeing if that changes anything... I'd be surprised if it did, though.

Comment: Well, 10-11-12 are exactly the months in the range... So _somewhere_, micht even be svn itself.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried switching them and it seems to have made the problem worse, but it might just be the same. Definitely not better.

Comment: I hope, you are aware of "Is Subversion a Day Early?" note in SVN book? Can you show any log sample?

Comment: and `{"DATE"}` or `{'DATE'}` format of string is *recommended*

Comment: @LazyBadger I'm not aware of that note, and I'm not sure what you mean by the format being recommended. How does that contrast with what I'm using now? When I try to use {"2012-12-10"}:{"2012-12-12"}, it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: @LazyBadger as for a log sample, here's a log entry that I would not like include but was included: r31 | <user redacted> | 2012-11-27 12:23:08 -0600 (Tue, 27 Nov 2012) | 1 line

Comment: @RiverTam - regaring `'` or `"` around date spec: it's OS-dependent (which to use in pure command-line) - in Win (cmd.exe) I use "DATE", in bash 'DATE', it changes from your format by *using chars around date-string* contrary to your: `{2012-12-10}` !=  `{'2012-12-10'}`

Comment: @RiverTam - for log entry - if it **first and single** records before revisions in correct range, it's OK. If no - we have to check more